# How can I use lambda expression here?

Tags: kotlin, lambda, android-volley

I have my custom GetVolley Class

```kotlin
class GetVolley(private val mContext: Context, private val url: String, private val onVolleySuccess: OnVolleySuccess?, private val mOnVolleyError: OnVolleyError?, private val mOnVolleyEnd: OnVolleyEnd?) {
    private fun getDataVolley() {
        Log.d("GetVolleyUrl", url)
        val request = JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, Response.Listener { response: JSONObject ->
            Log.d("GetVolleyResult", response.toString())
            if (response.has("result") && response.getBoolean("result")) {
                onVolleySuccess?.onSuccess(response)
            } else if (response.has("message")) {
                if (mOnVolleyError != null) mOnVolleyError.onError(response.getString("message"))
                else Toast.makeText(mContext, response.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
            mOnVolleyEnd?.onEnd()
        }, Response.ErrorListener { volleyError: VolleyError ->
            Log.d("GetVolleyError", volleyError.message.toString())
            val errorMessage: String = if (volleyError is NetworkError || volleyError is AuthFailureError) {
                "No Internet…"
            } else {
                "Undefinded error"
            }
            if (mOnVolleyError != null) mOnVolleyError.onError(errorMessage)
            else Toast.makeText(mContext, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            mOnVolleyEnd?.onEnd()
        })
        Volley.newRequestQueue(mContext).add(request)
    }

    init {
        getDataVolley()
    }
}
```

Interfaces in different files:

```
interface OnVolleySuccess {
    fun onSuccess(response: JSONObject)
}
______________________________________
interface OnVolleyError {
    fun onError(error: String)
}
______________________________________
interface OnVolleyEnd {
    fun onEnd()
}
```

When I use my custom GetVolley request. My code look like:

```
GetVolley(this, url, object : OnVolleySuccess {
    override fun onSuccess(response: JSONObject) {
        parseResponse(response)
    }
}, object : OnVolleyError {
    override fun onError(error: String) {
        showError(error)
    }
}, null)
```

I want it to look like this:

```
GetVolley(this, url, response -> {
    parseResponse(response)
}, error -> {
    showError(error)
}, null)
```

All my callbacks is nullable, so I can set null onVolleySuccess, onVolleyError, onVolleyEnd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you what is called [SAM conversions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#sam-conversions) (Single Abstract Method). It's only available to Java interfaces, but will be available to Kotlin interface from Kotlin 1.4. (see [this article](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2019/12/what-to-expect-in-kotlin-1-4-and-beyond)). Now if you want lambdas, use lambdas:

```
class GetVolley(
    private val mContext: Context, 
    private val url: String, 
    private val onVolleySuccess: ((response: JSONObject) -> Unit)?, 
    private val mOnVolleyError: ((error: String) -> Unit)?, 
    private val mOnVolleyEnd: (() -> Unit)?
) {
```

And instead of doing:

```
onVolleySuccess?.onSuccess(response)
```

You do:

```
onVolleySuccess?.invoke(response)
```

Comment: version 1.4 is not released yet, so can I use this version in production? or maybe i should wait it for release?

Comment: You can use it (see @AnimeshSahu answer), but I strongly encourage you to use lambdas instead, it's more idiomatic. Also 1.4 isn't stable yet.

Comment: @ShuhratjonJumaev EAP are not ready for production https://kotlinlang.org/eap/ `By participating in the EAP, you expressly acknowledge that the EAP version may not be reliable, may not work as intended, and may contain errors.`

Comment: @Nicolas I used your solution. And it worked without addtional interfaces, and my code looks better which I liked. It’s so not important, by the way my code look like this now:
```
GetVolley(this, url, {//it: JSONObject
    parseResponse(it)
}, {//it: JSONObject
    showError(it)
}, null)
```
Can that "it" be replaced with "response"?

Comment: Yes, `it` is just the default name. You can write `{ response ->` to name it.

Comment: @Nicolas thank you! This is what i absolutly needed.
PS... Sorry for that unformatted code in my comment. I could not format that))).

Answer (score 1):

**Note: Use Nicolas solution if you want, as it uses lambda natively if you don't want to use these classes in Java**

SAM conversion, i.e. interfaces to callbacks conversion using lambda is only available since Kotlin 1.4, which is in EAP (Early Access Program).

If you have [Kotlin 1.4-M1](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2020/03/kotlin-1-4-m1-released/) which is currently being released a few months ago, you can declare your interface with a `fun` keyword which will make it available to be used as lambda.

```kotlin
fun interface OnVolleySuccess {
    fun onSuccess(response: JSONObject)
}
fun interface OnVolleyError {
    fun onError(error: String)
}
fun interface OnVolleyEnd {
    fun onEnd()
}
```

Now you can use it like this:

```kotlin
GetVolley(this, url, { response ->
    parseResponse(response)
}, { error ->
    showError(error)
}, null)

// or simply
GetVolley(this, url, { parseResponse(it) }, { showError(it) }, null)
```

---

If you are having difficulties in adopting Kotlin 1.4, here's the catch:

```
// add/change these in build.gradle:
plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.4-M1'
    // ...
}

repositories {
    // ...
    maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap' }
}

// add these in settings.gradle
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { "https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap" }
        maven { "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
    }
}
```